# Error en app Android java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: lenght = 10; index = 10

Tags: java, android, array

Estoy haciendo en pequeño proyecto en Android Studio y cuando quiero pasar de una activity a otra, la app se cierra y me aparece ese error. El problema surgió cuando intente implementar el siguiente método:

```
public void NumAleatorio(){
    if(score <= 9){
        numAleatorio_uno = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        numAleatorio_dos = (int) (Math.random() * 10);

        resultado = numAleatorio_uno + numAleatorio_dos;

        if(resultado <= 10) {

            for(int i = 0; i <= numero.length; i++){
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(numero[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
                if(numAleatorio_uno == i){
                    iv_Auno.setImageResource(id);
                }
                if (numAleatorio_dos == i){
                    iv_Ados.setImageResource(id);
                }
            }
        } else {
            NumAleatorio();
        }
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity_Nivel2.class);

        string_score = String.valueOf(score);
        string_vidas = String.valueOf(vidas);
        intent.putExtra("jugador", nombre_jugador);
        intent.putExtra("score", string_score);
        intent.putExtra("vidas", string_vidas);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
    }
```

Lo que intento hacer es generar dos números aleatorios que sumados no sean mayor que `10`. Serían `numAleatorio_uno` y `numAleatorio_dos`. Después, asignar una imagen en dos `ImageView` (`iv_Auno` y `iv_Ados`), dependiendo del número aleatorio que haya generado java en `numAleatorio_uno` y `numAleatorio_dos`.

Anteriormente a este método había declarado un vector de `Strings` llamado `numero[]`, que utilizo en el metodo `getIdentifier()` para generar la dirección de la imagen y guardarla en la variable `id`.

Utilizo la recursividad en el `else` que vuelve a invocarse a si mismo `NumAleatorio()`; para evitar que la suma de la variable resultado sea mayor que `10`.

Y finalmente paso a otra Activity enviándole 3 variables (`nombre_jugador`, `string_score`, y `string_vidas`)

Agradecere mucho cualquier aporte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es muy claro. Tu array es de tamaño `10` y llegas al índice (posición) `10` y eso está fuera de tu array, dado que la primera posición es la `0` y la última la `9`.

El problema lo tienes en el `for`. Estás recorriendo desde `i = 0` hasta que `i` sea **menor o igual** que el tamaño. Y debería ser solo **menor**:

```
for( int i = 0; i < numero.length; i++)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, le reste 1 a numero.lenght y la app se dejo de cerrar al pasar a la siguiente activity, funciona perfectamente :)

Comment: Restarle 1 es otra opción, sí, aunque un poco más confusa según lo pienso yo, pero... cuestión de gustos. Ahí no me meto ;). Puedes seleccionar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha parecido buena.

Comment: Si amigo, ya acepte la respuesta. Dime si hay otra cosa que puedo hacer para subir tu reputación y con gusto.